# How to fix "advmanager missing from the Android Studio"?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm just getting started learning Flutter. It's the first programming language I'm learning.

I followed all the steps correctly to install Flutter, Android Studio, and VS Code. I created the emulator and added 2 devices "Pixel 6 pro, Pixel 3a."

I opened VS Code with my new Flutter project, then clicked main.dart. I then clicked "Select a device to use" to open the emulator.

I clicked create new emulator to add my devices I added in Android Studio, but I got this response:

> avdmanager is missing from Android sdk.

How can I this issue? The Android emulator was suppose to start.

Comment: Shot in the dart: `flutter config --android-sdk /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk` ?